# How do I configure the usb to function as com3?

Tags: command-line, usb

I am new to Linux and am using Ubuntu 17.04. I have installed a windows program using wine and it is installed OK. The program is a Pro Chrono digital that uses an USB to emulate a com port.
My question is "How to set up the com port in Ubuntu?"

I have tried to install drivers for this device using wine but although it seems to work the usb dongle is not recognized when I plug it in. Everything works in a windows machine and the program will function with ubuntu except the program will not talk to the Pro Chrono.

```
bill@bills-lap-top:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
```

(Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio)--This is the dongle, so Linux is seeing it but the program is not.

Comment: Please plug in the dongle and run `lsusb -t` and include the output in your post. You need to have it working in Linux (which supports almost **all** USB-Serial dongles, and then make wine use that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the dongle talking by linking ttyusb0 to com 1-(sudo ln -s /dev/ttyUSB2 com1). To keep my answer short I searched for similar questions and found question labeled  “Ubuntu+wine, USB COM port issue. Simbolic link question “.

With this as a guide  I was able to get my problem fixed.